# Flask endpoints not found while successfully registered

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

## Background

My Flask application is initiated via uWSGI and uses nginx to serve the pages. These processes are running in a Docker container which I acces via http://localhost:5364. nginx serves pages at port 88 (within the Docker container), which are forwarded to port 5364 on my local PC.

In production (on servers), all works fine and is up and running. However, when running a local instance and accessing these pages on my local PC, errors occur.

Using `print(app.url_map)` results in

```
Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> static>,
 <Rule '/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> home_page>,
 <Rule '/output-files' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> output_files_explanation>,
 <Rule '/invalid-submission' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> invalid_submission>
 <Rule '/results/download/<job_id>' (GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> result.return_user_download>,
 <Rule '/results/' (GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> result.result_from_job_id>,
 <Rule '/results/stage/<job_id>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> result.get_execution_stage>,
```

along with a few other routes. The URLS with the `results` prefix are from a Blueprint, registred as

```
result = Blueprint('result', __name__, template_folder="templates")
app.register_blueprint(result, url_prefix="/results")
```

in my `__init__.py`.

My nginx configuration file is below. My site is added to nginx/sites-enabled and nginx/sites-available. Again, in production all settings do not cause any errors.

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream flask {
    server unix:///tmp/<left_out>.sock; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      88;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location /static {
        alias <left_out>/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  flask;
        include     <left_out>/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

## Problem

When accessing http://localhost:5364/ , I get 404 not found errors, while the `/`-route is defined as shown in background. In contrast, URLs registered via Blueprints do not return 404 errors, but a 500 (internal server error ) error. This error happens because an error during URL generation occurred:

`werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home_page'. Did you mean 'tools.tools_page' instead?`

It seems that routes (not originating from a Blueprint) are registered in the URL-mapping, but are not found.

Any suggestions?